# Flatten class hierarchy for mapping and schema export (readonly base classes!)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have several entities to access the same table. I would like to put them in a class hierarchy. I don't want nhibernate to generate any joined-subclasses or discriminators in the mapping. When I return IsDiscriminated = false it makes joined subclasses which I don't need (and tries to schema export them).

I tried to use

```
public class SimpleFormConventions : IClassConvention, IClassConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.SchemaAction.None();
        instance.ReadOnly();
    }

    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IClassInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => Check(x.EntityType));
    }

    public static bool Check(Type type)
    {
        string typeName = type.FullName;
        string ns = type.Namespace;
        typeName = typeName.Substring(ns.Length + 1);
        return typeName.StartsWith("SimpleForm+");
    }
}
```

It runs correctly but the schema export ignores it and still tries to export these classes.. How can I achieve that each class is just treated as "flatten" to not generate joined-subclasses in the mapping? How can I disable schema export for these "SimpleForm" nested classes?

Comment: I think SchemaAction.None does not work because the ignored class has not ignored joined subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved all my hierarchy to abstract classes and set each entity to inherit the corresponding class from that hierarchy. As my ShouldMap ignores abstract classes now it works.